# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamic-proxy

I have windows service which access Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

I have a problem windows service giving exception when it trying to connect to CRM 2011.

It works fine when we run service directly from server.

I have an administrator privileges on CRM Organization what I am trying to connect.

This is the code where connecting to CRM:

```
  private OrganizationServiceProxy BuildCRMServiceProxy()
     {
         var credentials = new ClientCredentials();            
         var orgConfigInfo = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(OrganizationUri);
         return new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgConfigInfo, credentials);
     }
```

The exception is as below:

> ERROR 2013-08-21 09:27:47,958 [8] System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://*********/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc?wsdl'. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataLocationRetriever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper
>   timeoutHelper)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper
>   timeoutHelper)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper
>   timeoutHelper)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.ResolveNext(ResolveCallState
>   resolveCallState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(MetadataRetriever
>   retriever)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveServiceEndpointMetadata(Type
>   contractType, Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri,
>   Boolean checkForSecondary)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration.AdjustServiceEndpoint(Uri
>   serviceUri)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri
>   serviceUri)    at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri
>   serviceUri)    at
>   *****.DynamicsUpdater.ServiceAgent.DynamicsAgent.BuildCRMServiceProxy()    at
>   ******.DynamicsUpdater.ServiceAgent.DynamicsAgent.InsertEntity(String entityName, Boolean isRelationship, Dictionary`2 attributes, Guid&
>   generatedId)    at
>   ******.DynamicsUpdater.BusinessLogic.CRMProcessorFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3d`1.b__3c(Update
>   update, ICRMRepository CRM, IUpdatesRepository updatesRepo)    at
>   ******.DynamicsUpdater.BusinessLogic.Controllers.ApprovedUpdateController.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_1(Boolean
>   wasProcessedYet, Func`4 processor)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1
>   source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)    at
>   ******.DynamicsUpdater.BusinessLogic.Controllers.ApprovedUpdateController.Process(Update
>   update)    at
>   ******.DynamicsUpdater.BusinessLogic.Controllers.UpdateControllerBase.Execute(Func`1
>   retrieveUpdateForProcessingCallback)    at
>   ******.DynamicsUpdater.Updater.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_a()
>
> ---

Its work fine when we run it from windows server 2008 but not when I run from my desktop windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not providing valid credentials to the server. Is your desktop in the same network as the server? If so, try NetworkCredential:

```
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

Comment: Thank you pat for your answer it is in same domain. Actually I fixed it. I mistakely in app.config file set ServiceUri to "host/OrgName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationDATA.svc"; but should be "host/OrgName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"; so this fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks adeel, my ServiceUri was broken in a different way and your comment helped solved my problem.

Comment: @adeel yes thank you! exact same problem. been staring at that one for far too long!

Answer (score 0):

i was having same problem (ERROR : Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved )

but this error comes when i create new project called "New Visual Studio Solution Template for Dynamic CRM 2013" in Dynamic CRM node of C# in visual studio 2010.

it ask for domain name , and port number first and if u don't provide a valid domain name , it gives such error 
Domain name u will get from discovery service wsdl 
and no need to provide port , it will automatically fetch the available one . 
and than insert your credential and now you can create a project , which can be deployed on cloud .